# java: variable is never read/cannot find symbol

Tags: java, geometry, calculator

so i have to create a java program that calculates the diameter and area of a circle using methods: setRadius()and getRadius(). The setRadius() also has to be used to calculate the two values and set the radius. I used a constructor to assign radius as 1, but I also have to compute the diameter/area for a larger circle. When running the code, it says that it "cannot find symbol" with the diameter in the System print line. This is the code I have so far:

```
class My_Circle extends Main{
    float radius = 1;
    
    public float getRadius() {
        return radius;
    }
    
    public void setRadius(float newRadius) {
        this.radius = newRadius;
        float diameter = radius*2;
        float area = radius*radius*3.14159265359f;
    }
}

public class Main {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        My_Circle large = new My_Circle();
        My_Circle original = new My_Circle();
        
        large.setRadius(100);
        original.setRadius(original.getRadius());
        
        System.out.println("Large Circle Diameter: " + diameter);
        
    }
}
```

Comment: `diameter` is not visible from your `main` method.

Comment: @Arnaud a dumb question but, how do i fix that?

Comment: By stepping back. Ask yourself: you made `radius` a **field** of your whole class. But then you also defined **local** variables in this or that method. Ask yourself: what **should** be visible where?! You see ... both local variables diameter and area **only** exist in `setRadius()` method.

Comment: Hint: maybe, instead of computing those two values in that setMethod, you could add 2 other methods: `getDiameter()` and `getArea()`. And then, when you need the diameter of a Circle object, just call those method (or you can add those two numbers as fields to your class, and compute them once). And note: you could use a constructor instead of a setter. And: there is **no** reason at all at that your Circle class extends Main. Remember: you have to understand *every character* that you put into your source code. You dont extend Circle from Main because you *can*.

Comment: You only use those constructs that **make sense** to be used. Example: if you had a "Shape" base class, then it would make sense to extend Circle from that. But your Main class is just the entry point, the "driver" that is used to invoke some code in the end. No need to make Circle a Main.

Comment: Finally: read about java naming conventions. Class names go UpperCase, and you only use "_" in SOME_CONSTANT.

Answer (score 0):

`diameter` is out of scope in the Main class, because `diameter` is only declared when you call `setRadius()`
You need to declare `diameter` and `area` the same way you declared `radius`.

```
class My_Circle extends Main{
float radius = 1;
float diameter = radius*2;
float area = radius*radius*3.14159265359f;
```

Additionally, you need to create a getter method for diameter (like you did for radius)

Comment: This is bad advise. Your additional two fields there ... would be using a radius of 1. So when the setter gets called, the other values would stay at their initially computed number. So, if you really want to help, give a full example that addresses *all* issues in the code.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, your class My_Circle should not inherit from Main (remove the extends). Then you cannot get the variable diameter because it is not referenced anywhere in the Main class. If you want the diameter of the large circle just do large.getRadius() * 2 or add diameter variable in the same way you did for the radius. This way you will be able to do large.getDiameter().

Comment: *Then you cannot get the variable diameter because it is not referenced anywhere in the Main class.* Plain wrong. It is not about **referencing** in another place, it is about the fact that a **local** variable from one method isn't in the scope of another method. Please understand that all content here should have decent quality. If you lack the knowledge to clearly express a correct answer, consider to not write that down as answer.